# My minifigs have been doodled with marker pens. How can I clean them?

Tags: minifigures, cleaning

So simple question really, child drew on figures with marker pens, how can I clean them off with out removing the original prints ?

[image]

Comment: Rubbing alcohol **should** be able to remove marker pen marks without damaging the print (beware! I haven't tested this myself!!). Do **not** use acetone, since that'll remove the print.

Comment: @IvanSanchez acetone will dissolve (or at least attack) the plastic, never mind the print.  I'd consider denatured alcohol ("methylated spirits" here in the UK) rather than rubbing alcohol ("surgical spirit") because the non-alcohol components in the latter might be an issue.  Either way I wouldn't dip/soak/rinse for long before rinsing in water; I'd only try wiping if a simple dunk didn't work